# factory_girl association validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have an issue where I have a parent model `Foo`, which both `has_many :bars` and `has_many :bazes`.  Finally, I also have a join model `BarBaz` which `belongs_to :bar` and `belongs_to :baz`.  I want to validate all bar_bazes so that its bar and baz both belong to the same foo.  But I can't seem to figure out a way to define a factory for this model that would be valid.

```
Factory.define(:bar) do |bar|
  bar.association(:foo)
end

Factory.define(:baz) do |baz|
  bar.association(:foo)
end

Factory.define(:bar_baz) do |bar_baz|
  baz_bar.association(:foo)
  baz_bar.association(:bar)
  baz_bar.association(:baz)
end
```

I get an invalid record error when I try to create the latter, because the bar and baz factory_girl tries to associate it each have their own foo.  Am I screwed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after hours of beating my head against this issue, I think I finally have a solution.  It's pretty insane though, so hopefully someone else can still show me where I'm being stupid.

```
Factory.define :foo do |foo|
end

Factory.define :bar do |bar|
end

Factory.define :baz do |baz|
end

Factory.define :foo_with_baz do |foo|
  foo.after_create { |foo| Factory(:baz, :foo => foo) }
end

Factory.define :bar_baz do |bar_baz|
  bar_baz.bar {|bar| bar.association(:bar, :foo => Factory(:foo_with_baz))
  bar_baz.after_build {| bar_baz| bar_baz.baz_id = bar_baz.foo.bars.first.id }
end
```

The key issue being that there needs to be a foo in the database already you can get at through the factories alone, since you can use local variables or arbitrary ruby code in factories.rb (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Well, it can't be that great because after coming back to it after a few months I can't remember what the hell I was doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

The insaneness of creating factories with deeply nested associations led me to create [fixie](http://github.com/look/fixie) which lets you create test records using ActiveRecord. It runs during the `db:test:prepare` step. I use it to eliminate the need for fixtures. You can continue to use factories for easier-to-build objects.

Comment: I really like that, but why can't we make our factory solution allow arbitrary Ruby code in Factory definitions?

Comment: You can to some extent. The trick you need to work around is that factories are called many times and need to produce a valid object each time. This gets messy with associations.